# What’s the normal software-engineering adjective which means that a function tolerates bad input?

Tags: adjectives, terminology, programming, software, tech-writing

There's a term used in software engineering that I can't recall, but which usually describes a subroutine that tolerates bad input.

For example, let's say there's some method that converts raw string to an enum:

```
T StringToEnum<T>(string rawValue) where T : enum
```

How would you describe this method if it tolerates `rawValue`s that are not present in `T`, in which case it just returns the parsed `int` value, which works only thanks to the fact that enum is an integer?

It's not "tolerating", not "forgiving", but something else...what is it?

Comment: Why not "forgiving"? Were you think of "fault tolerant"?

Comment: @rajah9, there's just another word that's on the tip of my tongue which I can't recall. note that it's not *fault tolerant*, because it's not a fault per-se, though that's arguable.

Comment: How about "robust"?

Comment: For *tolerates*, you mean *allows* or *accepts*.

Answer (score 3):

Such software can be described as **robust**:

> In computer science, robustness is the ability of a computer system to cope with errors during execution and cope with erroneous input. ... Formal techniques, such as fuzz testing, are essential to showing robustness since this type of testing involves invalid or unexpected inputs.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_(computer_science))

Comment: Cf. Postel’s Law: Be liberal in what you accept and conservative in what you produce.